# Single sign-on and user's file (web page content) access

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, openid, openid-connect, owncloud

I don't want to store passwords on my server and I don't want to force my end users to create yet another account, that's why I'd like to use single sign-on. I'm looking for a widely accepted solution for the authentication, I think about OpenID and OpenID Connect, the former seems to be more widespread but obsoleted and no longer used by Google, the latter seems to be faster (thanks to JSON?), safer but less widely adopted.

I'd like to share some documents on Internet. I want to control who can view them. I have looked at OwnCloud but it seems to be too much for my needs.

My website contains some photos and some articles, I want to show some of them to everybody, I want to show some of them only to my family and my best friends but not my colleagues, I want to show some of them to all logged users but not everybody and finally, I want to show some of them to … nobody.

I use Apache HTTP Server, I want to be able to manage file access rights for my end users with their own means of authentication. I have looked at [mod_auth_oid](http://auth-openid.sourceforge.net) and mod_auth_oid_file, it handles the authentication with OpenID 2.0, it allows to define a [mapping](http://auth-openid.sourceforge.net/file_mapping.html) between OpenID and local user ids. Does it mean that I still have to store a password for each local user anywhere on my server?

> A graceful server restart is required in order to load new mapping definitions

It's a bit annoying as I don't want to restart the server each time I edit the mapping. It's unclear to me whether it is still true when using [mod_auth_oid_ldap](http://auth-openid.sourceforge.net/ldap_mapping.html). I really need an open source software that I can install on my server and adapt to my needs. I plan to use openid-selector with the Apache modules I mentioned earlier and some JavaScript code to handle gracefully the display of the forbidden content. Am I missing a more obvious solution? I'm not a big fan of Facebook but is [this bridge](http://facebook-openid.appspot.com) working?

Comment: "*I don't want to force my end users to create yet another account*" --> Do you want to make use of identities from Google/Facebook? i.e. Do you plan on making use of their authentications? If yes, you need to register your app with an identity provider (G!, FB etc). After the user authenticates, you get the userId. Now, you should have created authorization rules for the users which you will apply then, and permit/not-permit access to the articles/photos.

Comment: Actually, I plan to use the bridge between Facebook and OpenID that I mention at the very last line of my question in order to avoid using directly Facebook Connect which would require to register my application and I'd like to do something similar for Google but I'm not sure that it is possible according to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect After that, I'd like to use some regular expressions to create a mapping between OpenIDs and usernames. I don't want to register myself at each provider.